# Postgres query which shows when autovacuum (freeze) is launched

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

Help me please to write query which shows when on each table it is time
to start autovacuum (freeze). I mean when 'vacuum_freeze_table_age'
is on.

I've got Postgres 11. I wrote query, but it seems not wright:

```
SELECT   
        age(c.relminmxid) - current_setting('vacuum_freeze_table_age')::int8           as left_for_vacuum_freeze
from (pg_class c 
      join pg_namespace n on (c.relnamespace=n.oid)
     )
where c.relkind IN ('r','m','t') --and (age(c.relfrozenxid)::int8 > (current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age')::int8 * 0.8))
      AND n.nspname not like ('pg_temp%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT oid::regclass AS table_name,
       /* number of transactions over "vacuum_freeze_table_age" */
       age(c.relfrozenxid)
       - current_setting('vacuum_freeze_table_age')::integer AS overdue_by
FROM pg_class AS c 
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','m','t')  /* tables, matviews, TOAST tables */
  AND age(c.relfrozenxid)
      > least(
           /* it is ok to go a bit beyond the limit where VACUUM is triggered */
           current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age')::integer + 50000000,
           /* but at this point, we'll get warnings */
           2^31 - 40000000
        )
ORDER BY /* worst first */ age(c.relfrozenxid) DESC;
```

I chose not to report a table unless it it 50 million transactions over `vacuum_freeze_table_age`, because there is nothing wrong with that. Only if anti-wraparound autovacuum is a couple of million transactions overdue, you should start to worry. If you prefer to start fretting *before* anti-wraparound autovacuum hits, change `+ 50000000` to `- 10000000` or so.

Comment: Am I wright according to my and your query, that autovacuum becomes FREEZE on table after this statement is more then 0 (zero): age(c.relfrozenxid) -current_setting('vacuum_freeze_table_age')::integer ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: then I have to change in my query according to your the statement from: age(c.relminmxid)
       - current_setting('vacuum_freeze_table_age')::integer
to: 
age(c.relfrozenxid)
       - current_setting('vacuum_freeze_table_age')::integer